# HTML URL parameters getting encoded. How can I decode them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm making a website for a hackathon using `EJS` and `Express`. I use `Axios` to fetch data from an `API`. When I search for something in the project, then go to the next page using the buttons below and then back again I get different results from the API. My URL is changing. In example I search `space`. I get this URL: `https://lldev.thespacedevs.com/2.2.0/launch/?mode=list&limit=3&search=space&format=json`. When I get to the next page everything works and when I go back I get this URL: `https://lldev.thespacedevs.com/2.2.0/launch/?amp%3Blimit=3&amp;amp%3Bmode=list&amp;amp%3Boffset=3&amp;amp%3Bsearch=space&amp;format=json&amp;limit=3`

My fetching function:

```js
const fetch = require("axios");

module.exports = async function getData(url, params) {
    let body = await fetch(
        url ||
            `https://lldev.thespacedevs.com/2.2.0/launch/?mode=list&limit=3&${params}&format=json`
    );

    let json = await body.data;

    let rocketData = [];

    if (json.results.length === 0) return false;

    json.results.forEach((result) => {
        let date = new Date(result.net);

        let formattedDate =
            [
                new String(date.getUTCDate()).padStart(2, "0"),
                new String(date.getUTCMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0"),
                date.getUTCFullYear(),
            ].join("/") +
            " " +
            [
                new String(date.getUTCHours()).padStart(2, "0"),
                new String(date.getUTCMinutes()).padStart(2, "0"),
                new String(date.getUTCSeconds()).padStart(2, "0"),
            ].join(":");

        rocketData.push({
            previous: json.previous,
            next: json.next,
            name: result.name,
            date: formattedDate,
            lsp: result.lsp_name,
            location: result.location,
            image: result.image || "/assets/imageNotFound.png",
            status: result.status.name,
            statusDescription: result.status.description,
        });
    });

    return rocketData;
};
```

My search handler:

```js
const router = require("express").Router();

const getData = require("../fetchFromAPI");

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const query = req.body.query;

    const rocketData = await getData(null, `search=${query}`);

    if (!rocketData) return res.redirect("/no_results_found");

    res.render("pages/search", {
        title: "SpaceTime",
        rocketData: JSON.stringify(rocketData),
    });
});

router.post("/next", async (req, res) => {
    const next = req.body["next-url"];

    const rocketData = await getData(next);

    if (!rocketData) return res.redirect("/no_results_found");

    res.render("pages/search", {
        title: "SpaceTime",
        rocketData: JSON.stringify(rocketData),
    });
});

router.post("/previous", async (req, res) => {
    const previous = req.body["previous-url"];

    const rocketData = await getData(previous);

    if (!rocketData) return res.redirect("/no_results_found");

    res.render("pages/search", {
        title: "SpaceTime",
        rocketData: JSON.stringify(rocketData),
    });
});

module.exports = {
    path: "/search",
    router,
};
```

Buttons EJS component:

```js
<% if (JSON.parse(rocketData)[0].previous) { %>
<form action="/search/previous" method="POST">
    <input
        type="text"
        style="display: none"
        id="previous-url"
        name="previous-url"
    />

    <button>Previous page</button>
</form>
<% } %> <% if (JSON.parse(rocketData)[0].next) { %>
<form action="/search/next" method="POST">
    <input type="text" style="display: none" id="next-url" name="next-url" />

    <button>Next page</button>
</form>
<% } %>

<script>
    <% if (JSON.parse(rocketData)[0].previous) { %>
    document.getElementById("previous-url").value =
            "<%= JSON.parse(rocketData)[0].previous %>";
    <% } %>

    <% if (JSON.parse(rocketData)[0].next) { %>
    document.getElementById("next-url").value =
            "<%= JSON.parse(rocketData)[0].next %>";
    <% } %>
</script>
```

Comment: Native JavaScript function: `encodeURIComponent` to encode and `decodeURIComponent` to decode params.

Comment: @code Where should I encode (in which file)? Also I should decode in the handler or the fetching function right?